# Making divs inside flex boxes shrink-wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

How would one go about making these div flex boxes shrink-wrap?

Ie. making these:

[image]

Into these:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/35hk7L84/1/

As if one were to set `flex-direction: row;` except I can't have them on the same line.

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
}
.other {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello other world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems unclear to me what is your problem or your desire layout... can clarify?

Comment: Thanks for editing the original post!  I now understand what you were asking and posted the answer!  Happy Coding! :)

Comment: you can do this without using flex for that go through my following answer

Comment: @SwapnilMotewar im afraid flex is the only choice atm: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/media-object/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for (change the `display` of the individual elements):

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.other {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px;   
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello other world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Useful resources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Other: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks -- but your answer is the same as the one below -- plus I'm having problems reproducing the actual issue I'm having in my app so I'm going to close this question for now.

Comment: @MarkBoulder My answer is not the same, run the Snippet...  I added `display:table` to the inner elements and it fits the text exactly how you asked.

Comment: I'll be damned! I'm sorry man -- your answer is awesome and it worked in my app as well. Cheers!

Comment: Btw this is in relation to http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/media-object/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using following code.

for more reference and also generating code for flex with all properties you can go through following link

```
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-css-flexbox-module--net-25655

http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/
```

```css
.main {
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: column;

}
.other {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need more help for flex you can visit above links

Comment: Yeah that'll do! Thank you so much Swapnil!

Comment: Actually no: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/35hk7L84/2/ -- it seems it will not shrink-wrap to each box individually.

Answer (score 1):

You will get what do u need that is every element having different size with shrinking itself as width of element but without using flex.

```css
.other {
 clear:both;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="other">
        <p>H</p>
    </div>
   
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="other">
        <p>Hello world12345678</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had sucess with the following:

```
 width: -moz-max-content;
 width: -webkit-max-content;
 width: max-content;
```