# Preventing div from breaking off and shooting down

Tags: css

As one resizes the window in the following example, is it possible to prevent `.small` from breaking off and shooting down, and having both it and `.big` remain where they are?

I plan to use media queries to change the layout for smaller screens but right now `.small` is breaking off before the media query resolution is reached, making the user experience less pleasant.

http://jsfiddle.net/7q9jbuns/

```css
.main {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.big {
    float: left;
}
.small {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <p>Using display table so the box will wrap to this text</p>
        <p>Ref. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190514/making-divs-inside-flex-boxes-shrink-wrap">StackOverflow #27190514</a></p>
        <div class="big">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" />
        </div>
        <div class="small">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50/50" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want small div to drop down, what is going to happen? resize the big div, or trigger scrollbar?

Comment: Is it possible to resize the big div?

Comment: Preferably it should just stay in the same place until the media query takes over and disables the float at mobile sizes.

Comment: Can you switch `big` and `small` divs (can you edit html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using CSS table layout.** Wrap the two divs into a container.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouuabo1L/)**

```css
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.images {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.big, .small {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.small {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <p>Using display table so the box will wrap to this text</p>
        <p>Ref. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190514/making-divs-inside-flex-boxes-shrink-wrap">StackOverflow #27190514</a></p>
        <div class="images">
            <div class="big">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" />
            </div>
            <div class="small">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/50" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Using CSS flexbox.** Again, requires to add the container.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aq5wmnzL/)**

```css
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.images {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: columns;
    -ms-flex-direction: columns;
    flex-direction: columns;
}
.big {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <p>Using display table so the box will wrap to this text</p>
        <p>Ref. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190514/making-divs-inside-flex-boxes-shrink-wrap">StackOverflow #27190514</a></p>
        <div class="images">
            <div class="big">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" />
            </div>
            <div class="small">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/50" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a `min-width` to your `.main`, with the width required to keep it from wrapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqg3r8f3/

Comment: Nice solution, but unfortunately the width of `.main` changes from article to article.

Comment: Thanks Mark. You could use JavaScript (or whatever your application's framework provides for dynamically assigning styles) to set the `min-width` as needed, but that might not be feasible in your case. There may be a flexbox solution that meets your needs using just CSS, but I'm not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
white-space: nowrap;
/* (overflow: hidden;) */
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, the container itself has to wrap for maximum fluidity. You can see the reference SO question for more info.